# Installing Adobe Flex builder in Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: apache-flex, ubuntu

Is working fine?, i found instruction in Adobe site confusing and i am not confident at all since it says that only works with eclipse 3.3 (actual version should be 3.5 or close)
There is any special instructions to do it well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're talking about the Alpha version (found here: [Adobe Flex Builder 3 for Linux](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/flexbuilder_linux/)), it's not going to work at all. The commercial version doesn't support Linux.

I've used the Linux beta previously and the install worked well (it's a Flash based installer) so you shouldn't have any issues.